# Text cursor turned into horizontal cursor, how to undo this?

Tags: python, scripting, interface

Maybe a silly problem, but a real one. Suddenly my text cursor turned into horizontal one:
[image]

How can I set it back to a regular one?
I've tried many shortcuts to undo this, I also can't find anything in text editor options... I would be grateful for some help.

Comment: Press the `Insert` key.

Comment: Thank you! :) I'd accept this as an answer if you wish, I can't accept as a comment.

Comment: Yeah it was too short for an answer.  I had to babble a bit below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Press the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key.  The horizontal cursor means you're in "overwrite" mode, which can be toggled on and off with this key.

Comment: Note that this is standard behaviour in most programs in most operating systems. Some programs with custom text field implementations do not implement this feature (since it's rarely used), but IIRC default implementations for all of Linux, Windows and macOS do this. Blender chose to implement it too for consistency, since it has custom textboxes.

Comment: @Kroltan yes, absolutely.  This is not some hotkey, this is the very reason the Insert key was added to computer keyboards back in the day.